# Cannot execute cmd.exe using custom URI scheme on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cmd, uri-scheme

I'm trying to implement a custom URI scheme using `HKCU (HKEY_CURRENT_USER)`, but I am unable to make it work on Internet Explorer. I've created a key under `HKCU\Software\Classes` that just executes `cmd.exe`. It works in Chrome but when I try to call my custom URI in IE I get this error:

```
unable to open this helper application the protocol specified in this address is not valid custom uri
```

If I try to rename `cmd.exe` to `{anything_else}.exe` and update it in my Windows registry, it works. Is there any way I can execute `cmd` using a custom URI under `HKCU` on IE?

Comment: Not something I've come across before, but it sounds like you're hitting something in IE's security layer -- it's pretty logical that the system would think it a bad idea to be able to run arbitrary command line scripts from the browser; it would be a hacker's dream to be able to do that. I suspect that you might simply find this is not possible.

Comment: I see @Spudley, but if it works in Chrome I guess there must be a way to make it work in IE... or not

Comment: Chrome and IE don't run the same security code; there's no reason why they should work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it creating a `.bat` that executes `cmd`